# Grails 5 application name no longer getting added to the root of the url path when running locally

Tags: gradle, grails

I am in the process of upgrading a Grails application from version 3.3.16 to 5.3.2 and I'm finding that the URL of the application when running via `grails run-app` is just `http://localhost:8080`, when on Grails 3 it was `http://localhost:8080/myappname`.

Is there a reason for this change? I'm having a tough time finding anything about it in documentation. I'm assuming it's a change with the assembly process to the embedded Tomcat, but I'm not sure if there's a way I can change the naming of the deployed app there. Is there a way to get back to this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a context path to application.yml like:

```
server:
    servlet:
        context-path: /myappname
```